# Can PHP as slow as this?

Tags: php, performance, loops

I translated the Havlak benchmark from Robert Hundt into PHP ([see description](http://multi-language-bench.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/scaladays2011-paper/main.pdf)). You can find my version on [github](https://github.com/codenaschereien/havlakphp). The algorithm tries to find loops in a tree.
I tried to stay as close as possible to the java version. Unfortunately compared to the java version it is unbelievable slow and i cannot see a mistake so far. Whereas the java version needs less than a minute to run, the PHP version needs more than 8 hours on my client. So i guess there must be a mistake. But which one?

I went thru the hole algorithm again, but i coudn't find any major problems. But one thing is interesting: The test driver contains 15000 loops. I reduced it to one loop in the Java and PHP version. I get the following numbers using openjdk and PHP 5.4:

Java run:

> time make run
>    /usr/bin/java  \
>         -server -Xss15500k -cp .: LoopTesterApp
>   Welcome to LoopTesterApp, Java edition
>   Constructing App...
>     Total Memory: 31424 KB
>   Constructing Simple CFG...
>   15000 dummy loops
>   Constructing CFG...
>     Total Memory: 243520 KB
>   Performing Loop Recognition
>   1 Iteration
>     Total Memory: 446400 KB
>   done
>
> real  0m7.414s
>   user    0m8.954s
>   sys 0m0.484s

Now the PHP version:

> time php LoopTesterApp.php
>   Welcome to LoopTesterApp, PHP edition
>   Constructing App...
>    Total Memory: 512 KB
>   Constructing Simple CFG...
>   Constructing CFG...
>    Total Memory: 390912 KB
>   Performing Loop Recognition
>   1 Iteration
>    Total Memory: 835840 KB
>   done
>   real    6m38.110s
>   user    6m36.342s
>   sys 0m1.400s

Some calculations one this:
One run ins seconds in PHP (based on user time):  6 * 60 + 36.342 = 360.342 seconds
One run ins seconds in Java (based on user time): 0 * 60 + 08.954 = 008.954 seconds

Faktor: 360.342 / 008.954 = 40.2436899709627

Comment: I won't comment on the correctness of your implementation. I've found that PHP is often *much* slower than native or JIT'd code of many kinds (e.g: 5x slower than Perl5, 20x slower than Haskell). However, 1 minute versus 8 hours is going to either be: 1) dataset doesn't fit in memory, or 2) infinite loop.

Comment: As David said, yes it's slower, by anywhere from a factor of 3x to 100x: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=php&lang2=java&data=u64q.  But the result you are seeing is surely an implementation problem.  And SO isn't the place to ask people to look over your entire codebase

Comment: Based on the new calculations i added on top it's around faktor 40 which could be possible. It's possible it's just multiplied 15000 times and that's why it take so much time... @David: It should still fit in memory and it's no infinite loop, because it finishes.